# Reading PS/2 Keyboard Scan Codes on STM32 L476RG

Tags: c, stm32, usart, ps2

I am trying to read scan codes from a PS/2 keyboard on an [STM32 L476RG](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0351-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (NUCLEO L476RG dev board).

**PS/2 and USART:**

I *believe* that I can use the USART hardware on the STM32 to read PS/2 data, ***if there is a reason why not then please help me understand***. From my [reading](http://www.burtonsys.com/ps2_chapweske.htm) and observations with a scope, the PS/2 protocol sends the following packet format on the data line:

1. 1 start bit.  This is always 0.
2. 8 data bits, least significant bit first.
3. 1 parity bit (odd parity).
4. 1 stop bit.  This is always 1.

Each bit is captured on the falling edge of a separate clock signal that idles high. The clock on my particular keyboard sits at around 13.1 kHz.

Both systems will output at 3.3V from the keyboard if given 3.3V power, a a scope trace shoes that these waveforms are just fine while connected to the STM32.

**What's Going Wrong**

Basically, the system is not generating an interrupt when a key is pressed. The RXNE (receive buffer not empty flag) stays low and no interrupts are generated.

I go into more detail below, but if I use auto baud rate in "0x55" mode, an interrupt is triggered, but only because the auto baud rate error flag is set. All other modes do nothing (no interrupts).

**What I've Tried**

I use the following code to initialize USART1 on the STM32 to read from the keyboard:

```
void init_keyboard(uint32_t baud)
{
// Enable clock to GPIOA
RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;

// Enable clock to USART1
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;

// Configure UART
USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE  |   // Receiver enabled
               USART_CR1_PCE |   // Parity control enabled
               USART_CR1_PS  |   // Odd parity
               USART_CR1_M0  |   // 8 data bits
               USART_CR1_RXNEIE; // Enable RX interrupt

USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_TE);

USART1->CR2 |= USART_CR2_CLKEN     | // Enable USART clock (sync mode)
               USART_CR2_ABREN     | // Enable auto Baud Rate
               USART_CR2_CPOL;       // Clock polarit 1 (idle high)


// The following need to be cleared for sync mode
USART1->CR2 &= ~(USART_CR2_LINEN);
USART1->CR3 &= ~(USART_CR3_SCEN  |
                 USART_CR3_HDSEL |
                 USART_CR3_IREN);

USART1->BRR |= (SystemCoreClock / baud); // set baud rate

USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;

NVIC->ISER[1] |= (1 << (USART1_IRQn & 0x1F));

// Configure AF pins 8 and 10 to AF7 (USART)
GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (GPIO_AF7_USART1 << 0);
GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (GPIO_AF7_USART1 << 8);

// Configure PA8 (CK) and PA10 (RX) in alt. func. mode
GPIOA->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE8   | GPIO_MODER_MODE10);
GPIOA->MODER |=  (GPIO_MODER_MODE8_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODE10_1);

// Enable Global Interrupts
__enable_irq();
}
```

The data bits are LSB first by default, the capture is on the first edge (falling edge) by default and I confirmed that this baud rate / alternate function code works on a standard UART connection at 9600 baud.

I am also trying to use the auto baud rate detect since the baud rate of the keyboard seems to drift throughout the day (12.9 - 13.2 kHz) and I don't trust the baud rate to be stable. I tried with and without the auto baud rate and I tried auto baud rate in all 4 modes: (start bit measurement, falling-to-falling measurement, 0x55 frame detection, 0x7F frame detection). ***The only one that gives me anything is 0x7F, which throws an auto baud rate error whenever I read a code other than 0x55 (press a key besides '+'), but does nothing when I send a frame with 0x55 (press '+' key).***

And just in case you're wondering, I did call the function in main. :)

```
/* ISR for handling keypresses */
void USART1_IRQHandler(void);

int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  init_keyboard(13120);

  while (1) {/* wait for interrupts */ }
}


void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if (USART1->ISR & USART_ISR_RXNE)
    {
        char read_byte = USART1->RDR;
        while (1) {/* catch here for debugging */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no experience with PS/2, but.. 1) If clock is supplied by the keyboard, than STM's uart should be a synchronous slave 2) There is no reason to use auto-baudrate if the interface is synchronous

Comment: Thanks Flexz, that makes sense. I disabled auto-baudrate; I guess I'm not sure how I am supposed to get the USART to read bits in based on the clock, or how to make the STM run USART in synchronous slave mode. 

I thought setting CLKEN and CPOL and clearing CPHA would set up the timing to do this, but it doesn't seem to be reading in data on the clock edge.

Comment: I've looked in the RM, and found that STM32L476 is missing synchronous slave description section and SLVEN bit in the CR2 register, which are present in the STM32L4+ series, i.e L476 can only be a master in USART-sync mode. Looks like there is no easy way to receive PS/2 clocked data with the USART on STM32L476. Perhaps you could try some other approach - bit-banging or SPI-slave on the mcu side.

Comment: Hey @Flexz, that sounds right, just before you responded I decided to cut my losses and start bit-banging it. 

Thank you for putting in the time!

Comment: Actually, I can use the auto baud rate and just ignore the clock input entirely, this gives me the right data. Added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Flexz** for spotting the following:

> STM32L476 is missing synchronous slave description section and SLVEN bit in the CR2 register, which are present in the STM32L4+ series, i.e L476 can only be a master in USART-sync mode.

This means that I can't read from the PS/2 device as a slave, at least not using the clock. I ***can,*** however still read from the RX port asynchronously. This means that I do *not* want to enable CLKEN in USARTx->CR2.

If I treat the line asynchronously, then I can use the auto baud rate in mode 00 to capture the data even if the baud rate drifts, as it does on this keyboard.

**Final Code:**

```
void init_keyboard(uint32_t baud)
{
    //clear_buffer();

    // Enable clock to GPIOA
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN;

    // Enable clock to USART1
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN;

    // Configure UART
    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE  |   // Receiver enabled
                   USART_CR1_PCE |   // Parity control enabled
                   USART_CR1_PS  |   // Odd parity
                   USART_CR1_M0  |   // 8 data bits
                   USART_CR1_RXNEIE; // Enable RX interrupt

    USART1->CR1 &= ~(USART_CR1_TE);

    USART1->CR2 |= USART_CR2_ABREN;  // Enable auto Baud Rate

    USART1->CR3 |= USART_CR3_OVRDIS; // Disable overrun detection

    USART1->BRR |= (SystemCoreClock / baud);

    USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE;

    NVIC->ISER[1] |= (1 << (USART1_IRQn & 0x1F));

    // Configure AF pin10 to AF7 (USART)
    GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (GPIO_AF7_USART1 << 8);

    // Configure PA10 (RX) in alt. func. mode
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE10);
    GPIOA->MODER |=  (GPIO_MODER_MODE10_1);

    // Enable Global Interrupts
    __enable_irq();
}
```